# How do I clear certain lines/paths from a QWidget but not others, then redraw separate lines/paths on top?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to optimize line drawings on a QWidget. I basically have a grid in the background and drawings on top of the grid. Currently I'm redrawing the background and grid lines every time the paint event is called. This works fine if the grid lines are far enough apart so I don't have to draw that many lines, but if the scale gets changed, the lines must be redrawn at that new scale. Also, if the window is resized, then more of the grid is displayed, hurting the performance even more.

Here is the code for drawing the grid:

```
    // draw grid
    painter.fillRect(0,0,areaWidth, areaHeight, QColor(255,255,255));
    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(240,240,255)), 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap));
    int numXLines = areaWidth/mSIToPixelScale + 1;
    int numYLines = areaHeight/mSIToPixelScale + 1;
    double width = areaWidth;
    double height = areaHeight;

    for (int x=0; x<numXLines;x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<numYLines; y++)
        {
            painter.drawLine(0,y*mSIToPixelScale,width, y*mSIToPixelScale);
            painter.drawLine(x*mSIToPixelScale,0,x*mSIToPixelScale,height);
        }
    }
```

So when numXLines and numYLines in the above code reach higher values, the performance drops very hard, which makes sense. The grid will always have to be redrawn if the scale changes, but if the scale does not change, then only the drawing on top of the grid should change. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I went wrong, I was redrawing the y lines every x iteration. I fixed it by creating two separate for loops:

```
// add grid lines to a painter path
QPainterPath grid;
for (int x=0; x<numXLines;x++)
{
    grid.moveTo(x*mSIToPixelScale, 0);
    grid.lineTo(x*mSIToPixelScale, height);
}
for (int y=0; y<numYLines; y++)
{
    grid.moveTo(0, y*mSIToPixelScale);
    grid.lineTo(width,y*mSIToPixelScale);
}

painter.drawPath(grid);
painter.end();
```

Also, I think drawing onto a QImage first then drawing that image inside the paintEvent would make code more organized, so all your doing in the paintEvent is drawing from a high level.

Answer (score 0):

The [`QWidget::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* aEvent )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html) is called by the framework not just when you want it. So if you want to remove some lines from the widget than you need draw them conditionally in your function.

For example:

```
if ( numXLines < 25 && numYLines < 25 )
{
    // Draw only every second lines for example.
}
else
{
    // Draw all lines.
}
```

But this is not the best way. Maybe you shall use larger steps between the grid lines if there too many of them.

Comment: No, I don't want to remove lines from the widget. The numXLines and numYLines values are calculated above, and I need to draw all of those lines, not just a subset. The number of lines and the width of the line is calculated based on the window width and the current scale the user is using, so it would never try to draw outside that constraint. However, redrawing all the grid lines every time is bad for performance when a lot of lines are required. You can see this during window resizing for example when its constantly being refreshed.

Comment: I didn't wanted to say to remove all lines from the grid, I just wanted to tell you, that you may draw less lines when there are many of them.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that is not an acceptable solution, because I want to draw all the lines, and have good performance while doing so. It really should not be an issue to draw a couple hundred lines across the screen performance wise, but this is the case. It is purely a question of optimization, not changing the number of lines being drawn.

Comment: Do you try to draw only those lines which are visible ?

Comment: yes, that is why I calculate the number of lines and the length of those lines based on the visible area dimensions, so I am not drawing more than I need to. I believe what I need to do is draw outside of the paintEvent function onto a QImage, then plot the QImage onto the drawing area during the paintEvent, but so far when I try that, nothing is rendered to the image, it remains empty.

Comment: I don't think that that would be a good idea. Some years before I created a plot class and a `QWidget` was all I need. You need to draw everything in the `paintEvent`. If there are performance issues than you shall check the code of your `paintEvent` function. Benchmark the parts.